# OCaml - how to sort pairs?

Tags: sorting, ocaml

We have pairs:

```
 (3,10000) (1,2),(2,11) (2,0) (2, 10) (1,1000000)
```

And we would like to order:

```
 (1,2) (1,1000000), (2,0) (2, 10) (2,11) (3,10000)
```

How to do it in OCaml ?

Comment: I guess you have lists of pairs !

Comment: @user3052477 Forget my answer. I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 10):

The [List.sort](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALsort) function, which can sort any `'a list`, takes a comparison function of type `'a -> 'a -> int` that must return a negative number if the first argument is strictly smaller than the second, positive if it is strictly larger, and zero if they're equal.

```
let lexicographic_compare (x,y) (x',y') =
  let compare_fst = compare x x' in
  if compare_fst <> 0 then compare_fst
  else compare y y'

# List.sort lexicographic_compare [ (3,10000); (1,2); (2,11); (2,0); (2, 10); (1,1000000)];;
- : (int * int) list =
[(1, 2); (1, 1000000); (2, 0); (2, 10); (2, 11); (3, 10000)]
```

(This code uses the built-in `compare` function that does the right thing on integers.)

Note that in practice the `compare` function already compares pairs lexicographically, so `List.sort compare ...` (without writing any new code) would appear to work. How it works on pairs is not specified though, so it may change in the future and relying on this is bad style. If you want a precise comparison order, you should write your domain-specific comparison.

(Of course there are libraries out there that already provide this `lexicographic_compare` logic; but the point is to learn how to do it yourself.)

Comment: Nice answer, or we could use `Base.Comparable` to go there, like https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ocamlformat/blob/main/lib/Migrate_ast.ml#L98